# Constant Time Reverse Spliceing of List

Tags: c++, boost, stdlist

Given two `std::list<>`s `l1` and `l2`.
I can splice `l2` to the end of `l1` in O(1) constant time with `l1.splice(l1.end(), l2)`.
Sometimes, I need to splice `l2` in reverse, as in:

```
l2.reverse();
l1.splice(l1.end(), l2);
```

This operation will take time linear in the size of the `l2` due to the `reverse()` call.

I am looking for a method to do the *reverse-splice* in O(1) instead of linear time.

`std::list` is "usually implemented as a doubly-linked list", so at least in theory it might be possible to do. Also, `splice` does not accept reverse iterators.

Is there a way to do *reverse-splicing* in O(1)?
Is there some alternate implementation that allows this? I did not find something like this in boost.

Comment: Reversing a double-linked link is more of a trick, and can only be done if the list is implemented in a way that allows swapping head and tail pointers for that matter. Apparently, std::list is implemented in another manner, so the only solution would be to use another list structure, I suppose.

Comment: I did also not find such a thing in boost. Not in Boost Container, not in Boost Intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Some research brings up 3 approaches to do this:

The first is the [XOR Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list), which is a doubly-linked list implementation that makes use of a pointer-address math-"hack" to save memory space. It is also [naturally reversible](http://www.royvanrijn.com/blog/2010/11/xor-doubly-linked-list/) in O(1).

This [page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/revlist.html) describes another algorithm and also references [this paper introducing The Satellite Linked List](http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f08/Artikler/02/Osterman03.pdf).